# Different between Data Verification/Validation , Data Exploring/Exploitation, Data Acquisition/Collecting/Gathering?

Tags: data-science, data-mining, difference, glossary

What is the difference between these words in datascience?
is there any glossary exist to define these word?

-Data Verification / Validation

-Data Exploring / Exploitation

-Data Acquisition / Collecting / Gathering

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found just the first part of your question:

-Data Verification / Validation:
Data verification is a way of ensuring the user types in what he or she intends, in other words, to make sure the user does not make a mistake when inputting data. An example of this includes double-entry of data (such as when creating a password or email) to prevent incorrect data input. Data validation has nothing to do with what the user wants to input. Validation is about checking the input data to ensure it conforms with the data requirements of the system to avoid data errors. An example of this is a range check to avoid an input number that is greater/smaller than the specified range.